# What is the reverse assignment (destructuring assignment) in ES6 javascript?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

```
export const startAddExpense = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const {
      description = '',
      note = '',
      amount = 0,
      createdAt = 0
    } = expenseData;
    const expense = { description, note, amount, createdAt };

    database.ref('expenses').push(expense).then((ref) => {
      dispatch(addExpense(ref.key, ...expense));
    })
  }
}

export class AddExpensePage extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = (expense) => {
    this.props.startAddExpense(expense);
    this.props.history.push('/');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add Expense</h1>
        <ExpenseForm
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what `expenseData` is.  Why is the equal sign on the right?

What does the code say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [**destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax which was introduced in es6. It is a way to pluck values from an existing variable

```
const foo = { bar: 0, baz: 1 } 
const { bar } = foo
console.log(bar) // 0
```

the older way to write this would be

```
var foo = { bar: 0, baz: 1 } 
var bar = foo.bar
console.log(bar) // 0
```